# Is there a coding style for Blade templates?

Tags: php, coding-style, templates, laravel

Since when I used smarty I always tried to separate logic statements from html tags, so my approach to blade would be to write:

**template.blade.php**

```
<div>
    <div>
@if ($something == true)
        <ul>
    @foreach($list as $item)
            <li>
                {{ $item->name }}
            </li>
    @endforeach
        </ul>
@endif
    </div>
</div>
```

But the normal way I see this written is:

**template.blade.php**

```
<div>
    <div>
        @if ($something == true)
            <ul>
                @foreach($list as $item)
                    <li>
                        {{ $item->name }}
                    </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

But also sometimes directive is on the same column as preceding tag and sometimes tags are in the same columns as preceding directive.

I know is pointless to force my style if everybody else use a different one, no matter how much more sense makes to me, but is there any standard from Laravel?

Comment: I think it's better to write like the normal way you see. With the normal way you can sorting out all confusing lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

This often relies on preferences. BLADE doesn't have any special coding standards that differ from standard PHP in HTML. If you work in a company, there might be some standard set to keep the code consistent. Personally, I would advise to follow the normal way or to put your blade tags like this:

```
<div>
    <div>
    @if($something == true)
         <ul>
         @foreach($list as $item)
             <li>
             {{ $item->name }}
             </li>
         @endforeach
         </ul>
    @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

That way your html and blade tags flow in their own way, but it stays readable.

Comment: Thanks for your input, looks better than adding a tab after everything. Also I wanted to point out that there should be no space between @if and () that was my mistake, I guess you just did copy and paste.